# Files With Extension "doc" Must Show in Browser Instead of Download

Tags: html, doc

I have uploaded a doc file on my server and when i open this file by it's url then it's automatically downloaded but i want that this should open in a browser instead of downloading,please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: How would it open in a browser if it’s a Microsoft Word file (an educated guess)? And is this about opening a file by its URL, or about a link in an HTML document? The latter could be on-topic at SO.

Answer (score 0):

If you want open your document inside Browser, you can try the following settings:
The setting that controls this behavior is located in Windows Explorer (not Internet Explorer) on the user's machine.

1. Open “Windows Explorer”.
2. Select Tools -> Folder Options... from the menu.
3. Go to the “File Types” tab.
4. In the “Registered file types list”, select the file you want to change the setting for (e.g. DOC).
5. Click the “Advanced” button to open the Edit File Type dialog.
6. There is a checkbox, Browse in same window, where you can specify whether the selected file type should be opened within the browser or launched in its host application when clicked on a web page.

For more information, please refer to: http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;162059

Have you tried to use the page view web part and link to the document?

Also, does it have to be a word document?  Could you try a different approach for the content, like using one of the page layouts or the content editor web part?

Comment: <a href="example.doc" target="_self">Example</a> i wantto open the example.doc in a browser instead of downloading